# Teamcity CI throwing exceptions for python projects

Tags: python-3.x, teamcity

I am executing CI via Teamcity for my python project, which is deployed as an image in EKS

It was working fine suddenly I am getting the below error when teamcity is executing the Docker file.. the below error is when it tried to run pip install for the python packages. Could you please help me to understand/resolve this issue

```
ERROR: Exception:
[12:23:06]  Traceback (most recent call last):
[12:23:06]    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 169, in exc_logging_wrapper
[12:23:06]      status = run_func(*args)
[12:23:06]               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[12:23:06]    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 248, in wrapper
[12:23:06]      return func(self, options, args)
[12:23:06]             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[12:23:06]    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 377, in run
[12:23:06]      requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
[12:23:06]                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[12:23:06]    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 92, in resolve
[12:23:06]      result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
[12:23:06]                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[12:23:06]    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 546, in resolve
[12:23:06]      state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
[12:23:06]              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[12:23:06]    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 397, in resolve
[12:23:06]      self._add_to_criteria(self.state.criteria, r, parent=None)
[12:23:06]    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 173, in _add_to_criteria
[12:23:06]      if not criterion.candidates:
[12:23:06]    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/structs.py", line 156, in __bool__
[12:23:06]      return bool(self._sequence)
[12:23:06]             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[12:23:06]    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 155, in __bool__
[12:23:06]      return any(self)
[12:23:06]             ^^^^^^^^^
[12:23:06]    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 143, in <genexpr>
[12:23:06]      return (c for c in iterator if id(c) not in self._incompatible_ids)
[12:23:06]             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[12:23:06]    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 47, in _iter_built
[12:23:06]      candidate = func()
[12:23:06]                  ^^^^^^
[12:23:06]    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/factory.py", line 206, in _make_candidate_from_link
[12:23:06]      self._link_candidate_cache[link] = LinkCandidate(
[12:23:06]                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[12:23:06]    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 293, in __init__
[12:23:06]      super().__init__(
[12:23:06]    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 156, in __init__
[12:23:06]      self.dist = self._prepare()
[12:23:06]                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[12:23:06]    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 225, in _prepare
[12:23:06]      dist = self._prepare_distribution()
[12:23:06]             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[12:23:06]    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 304, in _prepare_distribution
[12:23:06]      return preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(self._ireq, parallel_builds=True)
[12:23:06]             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[12:23:06]    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 516, in prepare_linked_requirement
[12:23:06]      return self._prepare_linked_requirement(req, parallel_builds)
[12:23:06]             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[12:23:06]    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 587, in _prepare_linked_requirement
[12:23:06]      local_file = unpack_url(
[12:23:06]                   ^^^^^^^^^^^
[12:23:06]    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 166, in unpack_url
[12:23:06]      file = get_http_url(
[12:23:06]             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[12:23:06]    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 107, in get_http_url
[12:23:06]      from_path, content_type = download(link, temp_dir.path)
[12:23:06]                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[12:23:06]    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/download.py", line 147, in __call__
[12:23:06]      for chunk in chunks:
[12:23:06]    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/progress_bars.py", line 52, in _rich_progress_bar
[12:23:06]      with progress:
[12:23:06]    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/rich/progress.py", line 1169, in __enter__
[12:23:06]      self.start()
[12:23:06]    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/rich/progress.py", line 1160, in start
[12:23:06]      self.live.start(refresh=True)
[12:23:06]    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/rich/live.py", line 132, in start
[12:23:06]      self._refresh_thread.start()
[12:23:06]    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 957, in start
[12:23:06]      _start_new_thread(self._bootstrap, ())
[12:23:06]  RuntimeError: can't start new thread
```